# Get errors when I try to set ref in react component with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I get two errors when I try to set ref in react component.

```
import React from "react";

const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} {...props}/>;
});

export default Input;
```

```
Component definition is missing display name eslint(react/display-name).
"Type 'ForwardedRef<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement>'."
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forwardRef` is a generic. You can tell it what the ref will point to, and what props the component takes. Currently you're not doing so, so the defaults are that the ref is set to `unknown`, and the props are set to an empty object.

Assuming you want this component to take in all the same props that an `<input>` can take, you'd fix it like this:

```
type InputProps = React.DetailedHTMLProps<
  React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,
  HTMLInputElement
>;

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

> Component definition is missing display name eslint(react/display-name).

To address this lint error, give the component a display name:

```
Input.displayName = 'Example';
```